# Scalar function is non-deterministic

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, non-deterministic

I'd like to persist this field but can't figure out why it's non-deterministic.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetServiceMinutes
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @StartDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime
)
RETURNS int WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result int

    SET @StartDate = CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, @StartDate) < 8 THEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @StartDate), '08:00:00')  ELSE @StartDate END
    SET @EndDate = CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, @EndDate) >= 17 THEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @EndDate), '17:00:00') ELSE @EndDate END
    
    SET @Result = 
         CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, @StartDate) != DATEPART(DAY, @EndDate) THEN 1000
              WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, @EndDate) < 8 THEN 0
              WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, @StartDate) >= 17 THEN 0
              ELSE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, @EndDate)
    END
    
    RETURN @Result

END
GO
```

This returns 0

```
SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[dbo].GetServiceMinutes'), 'IsDeterministic')
```

Using SQL Server 2017

Comment: Implicit conversion of your (date and) time strings is a very likely candidate. That isn't allowed. It must be *explicit* with a style code.

Comment: I'm also confused by that expression. You are adding *days* to `'08:00:00'`, but that is clearly a `time`, not a date and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, as I alluded to, is your implicit conversions with (date and) time values. Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-ver15):

> The following functions are not always deterministic, but can be used in indexed views or indexes on computed columns when they are specified in a deterministic manner.
>
> | Function | Comments |
> | --- | --- |
> | all aggregate functions | All aggregate functions are deterministic unless they are specified with the OVER and ORDER BY clauses. For a list of these functions, see Aggregate Functions (Transact-SQL). |
> | CAST | Deterministic unless used with datetime, smalldatetime, or sql_variant. |
> | CONVERT | Deterministic unless one of these conditions exists: Source type is sql_variant. Target type is sql_variant and its source type is nondeterministic. Source or target type is datetime or smalldatetime, the other source or target type is a character string, and a nondeterministic style is specified. To be deterministic, the style parameter must be a constant. Additionally, styles less than or equal to 100 are nondeterministic, except for styles 20 and 21. Styles greater than 100 are deterministic, except for styles 106, 107, 109 and 113. |

In your function you have implicit casting, for example `'08:00:00'` to a `datetime`. You need to be explicit:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetServiceMinutes
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @StartDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime
)
RETURNS int WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result int

    SET @StartDate = CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, @StartDate) < 8 THEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @StartDate), CONVERT(datetime,'1900-01-01T08:00:00',126))  ELSE @StartDate END
    SET @EndDate = CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, @EndDate) >= 17 THEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @EndDate), CONVERT(datetime,'1900-01-01T17:00:00',126)) ELSE @EndDate END
    
    SET @Result = 
         CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, @StartDate) != DATEPART(DAY, @EndDate) THEN 1000
              WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, @EndDate) < 8 THEN 0
              WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, @StartDate) >= 17 THEN 0
              ELSE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, @EndDate)
    END
    
    RETURN @Result

END
GO

SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[dbo].GetServiceMinutes'), 'IsDeterministic')
```

Comment: That did the trick thanks!  The expression to get 8am for the date was something I found on here, it worked so I didn't give it much thought.